# Can JMeter be used to delete records from a database?

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I've been working with JMeter to put together some integration tests for a set of Servlets that I'm working on. I've now got several test suites that exercise different scenarios and assert on the responses sent back by the servlets.

The problem I've now got is that the tests don't have a clean database to work from when they are run together, so they are polluting one another and failing.

The documentation suggests that a JDBC PostProcessor should be used to clean up the database after a test runs, however I can't see a way to write a delete statement that will clear the tables down.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: I bet there is a preprocessor too

Comment: JMeter isn't for integration tests, it's for performance tests. If you want integration tests then use an integration testing tool and a test framework. That said, there are both pre- and post-processors, but I don't have it installed at the moment to check what statements are available besides prepared and callable.

Comment: You could use the JDBCPreProcessor to connect to the database and call "delete from ...." in the query.
So far I only used "Select ... from ..." which works fine and fits the purpose of the JDBCPreProcessor but I don't see a reason why "Delete from ..." shouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps it's better to use a tearDown ThreadGroup. In that you can use any Sampler you wish. So you can use a JDBC Sampler to execute your DELETE Statement.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The tearDown group runs after the main ThreadGroup, so it is suitable for my needs.

Comment: I had a few separate issues getting the JDBC delete statement to work, but that was related to my JDBC Confgiguration Element.

In case it is of any use to anyone else, you can set the Query type to "Update Statement" (still not entirely sure what this does) and then write your "DELETE FROM....." SQL in the query itself.

Now my tests clean up after each suite has run, which is great!

Answer (score 3):

You must choose Callable Statement in JDBC Request  as  `delete from Stocks where StockIdent=1`

Comment: improve your answer by adding important links and formatting it with the help of ctrl + K and other links